# Android how to call Method every N Hour O'Clock <<<<<<<<<<

Tags: android

I've created service that will be call Method every hour using loop, but cant exactly hour O'Clock ( N:00 ),
my code

```
    try {
        do {
            Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(UtilitiesGlobals.ONE_HOUR));
            publishProgress();
        } while (RUNNING);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, how i can call every Hour O'Clock ( 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00 .... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            todoItems.clear();

                            publishProgress();
                            handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 60 );
                        }
                    }, 60 * 60 );*
```

Comment: is it fine to use handler for hourly tasks?

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // your code here.
    }
};

// schedule the task to run starting now and then every hour.
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 1000*60*60);
```